# Did the other 3 founders of Hogwarts create secret passageways like Salazar Slytherin did?

Tags: harry-potter

We all learned and read in the Chamber of Secrets that Salazar Slytherin hid his Basilisk in the Chamber of Secrets, which he himself created. But did the other founders also create secret places at Hogwarts that haven't been discovered yet?

Comment: Hi Kyle, seeing your rapid questions activity today (Which includes many closed questions and downvoted and/or deleted questions), I think you probably do not know about the Question-ban mechanism on SE. Please take a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) to learn about it to avoid any problems in the future

Comment: I commented the same on one of your other posts IDK, I doubt you saw it given your persistence in  posting low quality questions. It is good to ask numerous questions but please make sure that you do the required research before asking the question. For example, this very question, the answer would be _No, not that we know if_ and I am not even into HP.

Comment: Dpn't be discouraged by the way, as someone who lives in the harry-potter tag, I appreciate many of your questions, but Aegon is absolutely right that it is about quality over quantity :)

Comment: Even if it's not quite a secret passage, Godric Gryffindor has created the Sorting Hat, which can read minds, speak, and, most importantly, give the sword of Gryffindor to someone who's worthy of it.

Answer (score 9):

### "No, not that we know [of]" - Aegon

There isn't anything in the books, the movies, or on Pottermore to suggest that the other founders also created secret areas. The Room of Requirement might potentially be such a place, but its origin and maker(s) are unknown.